# Property out of scope in C# function

Tags: c#, scope

I have the following problem:
I have 2 classes, let's say class1 and class2, I created in my main class.
I the class2 code I try to access a class1 property, GetFieldValue, which has a get method.
I tried to do so this way:

```
int fieldName;  
fieldName = main.class1.GetFieldValue;
```

The compiler tells me:
    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property....

Is there a way to do something like that?
I hope I have been clear :)

Comment: Show us your instance creation - looks like you're just accessing the type here.

Comment: Your property should be `static`, if you want to access it without class instance. Also `GetFieldValue` isn't a good name for property.

Comment: Class instance is created like this: ClassName istanceName = new ClassName(); I know names I've been using are not good, but at the moment I don't have the true code here right with me! thaks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to skin this cat; but I would recommend just injecting the instance of `Class1` into `Class2` like this:

```
private Class1 _c1;

public Class2 (Class1 c1)
{
    _c1 = c1;
}
```

and then later on:

```
_c1.GetFieldValue
```

Bear in mind that `GetFieldValue` will need to be either `public` or `internal` to access it.

So now, when you create `Class2`, you'd do it like this:

```
var c2 = new Class2(c1);
```

where `c1` is an instance of `Class1`.

Comment: Yes I know I could pass it to my function and store it in a same datatype field, but the function I would have to pass is full of stuff, all useless of me but that particular field I need! Is there a way to access it without passing anything during function call?? and by the way, thank you a lot for replying! :)

Comment: @user2979038, of course. As I stated, there is more than one way of skinning this cat. But you'd need some architecture. Where are you going to store the instance of the object instead? What is `main` in your question? What is `main.class1` in your question? Did you build any architecture there?

Comment: ok, sorry for bwing unclear. I have some problem describing the thing... I'm building an xna game and posting the real code is a bit complicated, I tryed to take some snippet but it results even more complicated..... Suppose I have a Class named Main in witch I istanciate 2 classes, Class 1 and Class 2, both public. I was trying to access Class 1 from inside Class 2 using a sintax like: int var = Main.Class1.data; where data is the field in Class1 I want to eccess.

Comment: @user2979038, you'd need to build a Singleton on the `Main` class, and the syntax would probably look something more like `Main.Instance.Class1.data;` after that.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'm about to read Microsort's web site about it! Could you suggest me a good c# book?

Comment: @user2979038, I couldn't suggest a good book, primarily because I've never read any. But any that were edited by Eric Lippert would be great.